# Has no member error when struct does have that member. Compiler ignoring declarations

Tags: c

I'm coming across an error in c in which the compiler gives the followings errors:

BEFORE you look at the errors just realize they majority are either saying I have something undeclared and then gives my struct name, or it says that my structname has no member named "head" or "tail"... and yet my structures do have those members...

```
File.c:31: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘LINKNODE’
File.c: In function ‘f1d’:
File.c:78: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘fwrite’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
File.c: In function ‘f2’:
File.c:86: error: called object ‘"ls -al "’ is not a function
File.c: In function ‘f4’:
File.c:115: error: ‘NLIST’ has no member named ‘head’
File.c:116: error: ‘LINKNODE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
File.c:116: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
File.c:116: error: for each function it appears in.)
File.c:116: error: ‘starter’ undeclared (first use in this function)
File.c:116: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
File.c:118: error: ‘NLIST’ has no member named ‘head’
File.c:119: error: ‘Linklist’ undeclared (first use in this function)
File.c:121: error: ‘NODE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
File.c:121: error: ‘ptr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
File.c:121: error: ‘NLIST’ has no member named ‘head’
File.c:122: error: ‘NLIST’ has no member named ‘tail’
File.c:126: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘NewNode’
File.c:127: error: ‘NewNode’ undeclared (first use in this function)
File.c:129: error: ‘NLIST’ has no member named ‘tail’
File.c: In function ‘f5a’:
File.c:168: error: ‘LINKNODE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
File.c:168: error: ‘NewNode’ undeclared (first use in this function)
File.c:168: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
File.c:170: error: ‘list’ undeclared (first use in this function)
File.c: In function ‘f5b’:
File.c:175: error: ‘NLIST’ has no member named ‘head’
File.c:175: error: ‘NLIST’ has no member named ‘head’
File.c: In function ‘printList’:
File.c:186: error: ‘LINKNODE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
File.c:186: error: ‘ptr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
File.c:186: error: ‘NLIST’ has no member named ‘head’
File.c: In function ‘createList’:
File.c:195: error: ‘LINKNODE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
File.c:195: error: ‘ptr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
File.c:195: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
File.c:196: error: ‘NLIST’ has no member named ‘head’
File.c:198: error: ‘nextone’ undeclared (first use in this function)
File.c:198: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
File.c:203: error: ‘NLIST’ has no member named ‘tail’
```

And my code does have these objects declared and the objects do have those associated members. It must be some simple syntax error that I have been overlooking. Here's the my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* for printf() and fprintf() */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* for socket(), connect(), sendto(), and recvfrom() */
#include <arpa/inet.h>  /* for sockaddr_in and inet_addr() */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for atoi() and exit() */
#include <string.h>     /* for memset() */
#include <unistd.h>     /* for close() */
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define ECHOMAX 255     /* Longest string to echo */

int sock;                        /* Socket descriptor */
struct sockaddr_in echoServAddr; /* Echo server address */
struct sockaddr_in fromAddr;     /* Source address of echo */
unsigned short echoServPort;     /* Echo server port */
unsigned int fromSize;           /* In-out of address size for recvfrom() */
char *servIP;                    /* IP address of server */
char *echoString;                /* String to send to echo server */
char echoBuffer[ECHOMAX+1];      /* Buffer for receiving echoed string */
int echoStringLen;               /* Length of string to echo */
int respStringLen;               /* Length of received response */


typedef struct node { 
    int storage;
    struct node *next;
} lINKNODE;

typedef struct nlist {
    LINKNODE *head;
    LINKNODE *tail;
} NLIST;

char *create_substring(char *s, int first, int last)
{
    int length = (last-first)+1;
    char *new_str = malloc(length+1);  //need an extra byte for the 0.
    strncpy(new_str, s+first,length);
    new_str[length] = '\0';
    return new_str;
}

void f1a(char *filename,char *string){
    FILE *writeto=(FILE *)fopen(filename,"a"); //fixed length? huh?
    fprintf(writeto,"%s",string);
    fclose(writeto);
}

void f1b(char *filename,int k){
    FILE *readfrom=(FILE *)fopen(filename,"r");
    char *c=malloc(1);
    int i;
    if (read==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"file not opened \n");
        return;
    }
    for (i=1;i<k-1;i++){
        fgets(c,1,readfrom);
    }
    fclose(readfrom);
}//change

void f1c(char *filename,int k){
    FILE *readfrom=(FILE *)fopen(filename,"r");
    fseek(readfrom,k,0); //third argument... 0??? whence? what? 
    char *c;
    fgets(c,1,readfrom);
    printf("The kth character is %s\n",c);
    fclose(readfrom);   //read the kth character? print character
}//offset t? return value?

void f1d(char *filename,int k, char *sentence){
    FILE *readfrom=(FILE *)fopen(filename,"rw");
    if (readfrom!=NULL){
        int k=fseek(readfrom,k,0);
        int f=strlen(sentence);
        fwrite(sentence,1,f,k);
        fclose(readfrom);}
    else {
        printf("File could not be opened\n");
    }
}
void f2(char *F,char *D){
    char *command="ls -al "
    strcat(command,D);
    strcat(command," | grep -E \"^([& ]+ +){7}.*");
    strcat(command,F);
    strcat(command,"\" > t1.out");
    system (command);
    char *filename="t1.out";//error check as he said
    FILE *readfrom=(FILE *)fopen(filename,"r");
    char *currentline=malloc(200);
    if (readfrom!=NULL){
        char *sentence=malloc(200);
        while (fgets(currentline,200,readfrom)!=NULL){
            printf("%s",currentline);
        }
    }
}

void f3(){
    int myArray[1000];
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<1000;i++){
        myArray[i]=rand();
    }
    int sum=0;
    for (i=0;i<1000;i++){
        sum+=myArray[i];
    }
    printf("The array sum is %i\n",sum);
}
void f4(NLIST *LinkList){
    if (LinkList->head == NULL){
        LINKNODE *starter=(LINKNODE *)malloc(sizeof(LINKNODE));
        starter->storage=100;
        LinkList->head=starter;
        Linklist->tail=starter;
    }
    NODE *ptr=LinkList->head;
    while (ptr != LinkList->tail){
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }

    LINKNODE NewNode=(LINKNODE *)malloc(sizeof(LINKNODE));
    NewNode->storage=0;
    Linklist->tail->next=NewNode;
    LinkList->tail=NewNode;
}







void initsocket(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if ((argc < 3) || (argc > 4))    /* Test for correct number of arguments */
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s <Server IP> <Echo Word> [<Echo Port>]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    servIP = argv[1];           /* First arg: server IP address (dotted quad)*/
    echoString = argv[2];       /* Second arg: string to echo */

    if ((echoStringLen = strlen(echoString)) > ECHOMAX)  /* Check input length */
        printf("Echo word too long");

    if (argc == 4)
        echoServPort = atoi(argv[3]);  /* Use given port, if any */
    else
        echoServPort = 7;  /* 7 is the well-known port for the echo service */

    /* Create a datagram/UDP socket */
    if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0)
        printf("socket() failed");

    /* Construct the server address structure */
    memset(&echoServAddr, 0, sizeof(echoServAddr));    /* Zero out structure */
    echoServAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                 /* Internet addr family */
    echoServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(servIP);  /* Server IP address */
    echoServAddr.sin_port   = htons(echoServPort);     /* Server port */
               }

void f5a(NLIST *LinkList){
    LINKNODE *NewNode=(LINKNODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    NewNode->storage=1231231;
    list->tail->next=NewNode;
    list->tail=NewNode;
}

void f5b(NLIST *LinkList){
    LinkList->head=LinkList->head->next;
}


void f6(){
    if (sendto(sock, echoString, echoStringLen, 0, (struct sockaddr *)
               &echoServAddr, sizeof(echoServAddr)) != echoStringLen)
        printf("sendto() sent a different number of bytes than expected\n");
}

void printList(NLIST *LinkList){
    LINKNODE *ptr=LinkList->head;
    while (ptr !=NULL){
        printf("%i\n",ptr->storage);
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
}

void createList(NLIST *LinkList){
    int i=0;
    LINKNODE *ptr=(LINKNODE *)malloc(sizeof(LINKNODE));
    LinkList->head=ptr;
    for (i=0;i<1000;i++){
        LINKNODE *nextone=(LINKNODE *)malloc(sizeof(LINKNODE));
        ptr->storage=i;
        ptr->next=nextone;
        ptr=nextone;
    }
    LinkList->tail=ptr;
}





int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    printf("%c",flb("Untitled 2.txt",5));
    char *sentence=malloc(200);
    FILE *readfrom=(FILE *)fopen("Untitled 2.txt","r");

    fclose(readfrom);
}
```

Comment: In general, StackOverflow isn't meant for syntax checking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is error-ridden. To mention just a few:

- You're creating a typedef `lINKNODE` instead of `LINKNODE`
- You're missing a semicolon after `char *command="ls -al "`
- You're using `Linklist` instead of `LinkList`
- You're saying `NewNode->storage=0;` where `NewNode` isn't a pointer

Comment: Well! I knew it would be a simple mistake.. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

After you have solved all the syntax problems you will find that your program is going to segfault due to the wrong usage of `strcat`.

`strcat` requires that the destination is large enough to hold the result of the concatenated string. Now you do:

```
char *command = "ls -al ";
```

This will actually declare a string literal which is usually put into readonly memory. When you try to append something to it then this is a write and it will fail. And even if you would do:

```
char command[] = "ls -al ";
```

This would still reserve only enough memory for the string "ls -al " and appending to it will cause weird bugs and probably a segfault at some random point as you will overwrite your stack contents. You ned to use `strlen` to find out how much memory you need, then allocate it with `malloc` and then use `strcpy` to copy all the values in.

Comment: Thank you! will it work if I write char command[200]; command="ls -al";

Answer (score 3):

You haven't defined a type called `LINKNODE`.  You've defined a type called `lINKNODE`, with a lowercase letter `l`.

That's just the first reported error.

When you get a cascade of error messages like this, carefully examine the very first one.  The rest are likely to be side effects of the compiler's confusion.  Fix the first error, recompile, iterate.  (And be wary of making changes just to make the compiler happy; code that compiles is not necessarily correct.)

Answer (score 3):

The first error is because you declare a typedef of `lINKNODE` but you probably inteded `LINKNODE`. I.e., the first letter was not capitalized properly.